# Top Solder (make top solder act as positive)

Tags: altium, solder-mask

I have need to manually place solder mask in a rf circuit as the dielectric of the solder mask effects signal too much. Normally this solder mask layer (top Solder) is a negative layer. Where you draw (or automatically) form a primitive it masks that area out to remove the solder mask in that area. I sort of need (and there may be other ways of doing this) to set the layer to NOT work in this normal way.

- Would be nice to set this on a 'per room' basis.
- The solder mask pieces should be visible in 3D view.

Best solution I have run into so far is, to make another layer (in mechanical) but it's not suitable as it does not appear in 3D view. Ideally it should just like the solder mask would appear in the 3D view.

Comment: You might let us know which CAD program you are using.

Comment: Why can't you just keep the solder mask as a negative layer and draw features over the RF regions where you want the mask removed?

Comment: A picture of the different layers would be helpful. Copper pour only, then with/without solder mask, stackup & location of grounding vias etc etc.

Comment: eCAD tool is altium. Put it in as a tag but missed it in the question.

Comment: @ThePhoton because I want the solder mask layer to be a 'positive' construction of starting with no solder mask and building it manually. This is the opposite of how 99% of users needs are.

Comment: @abaddon, any features you can draw with a positive layer you can draw in negative on a  negative layer, so I still don't understand why you (sort of) "need" to have it as a positive layer.